# SQL Server Trigger - Need to Alter

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to alter a trigger in SQL Server. After I am doing, do I just execute the trigger similar to how I would do for a Stored Procedure?

```
    ALTER TRIGGER
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is right, just use `ALTER`. If you right-click on your trigger in Object Explorer in SSMS and select *Script Trigger as/ALTER To*, you will see the `ALTER` statement created for your trigger.

Comment: Thanks. I would run the Execute after I have modified the trigger for the trigger to be in effect, correct?

Comment: @NatePet No, the trigger is enabled immediately after your `CREATE TRIGGER` or `ALTER TRIGGER` statement completes.

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TRIGGER triggerName
ON tableName
FOR INSERT -- or update & delete
AS 
 -- sql here
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176072.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You don't "execute" a trigger. Triggers are "triggered" at certain points depending upon your definition of them.

For example an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger would run **for all rows updated** after you send an `UPDATE` command to the table on which the trigger is created.

Comment: @RedFilter If so, that's like asking *"How do I execute a `SELECT` statement?"* It's kind of a non-question, IMHO. He did ask if he could *"execute the trigger similar to how I would do for a Stored Procedure"* - and with triggers you can't explicitly **make** them run.

Comment: Perhaps you are right - you get all levels of questions here, so I am never sure.