# Alter All Triggers via T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Is there a way to update/alter all triggers using Looping T-SQL or a C# Code ?. I need it too update all the triggers in my database because the `RAISERROR` command has changed in sql server 2012.

Comment: Did you even try `ALTER TRIGGER`?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables im not talking about manually create alter script for each of the triggers. What i want is to create a Loop through each of my triggers let's say I have 500 triggers and Replace a specified syntax/command to a new one

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the proposed duplicate [SO 8607262](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8607262).  That's about a single ALTER TRIGGER; this is about automating many of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all trigger using

```
SELECT [name] FROM [sys].[triggers]
```

and loop through each trigger and execute

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'TriggerName'
```

so you will have the create statement with it...

Comment: thanks for this. Maybe this is the only way, to get the create script and tweak the RAISERROR syntax to the new one.
THANKS!!

Answer (score 3):

You can script out all the triggers into a text file. See:

[How to Generate Scripts For All Triggers in Database Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200511/how-to-generate-scripts-for-all-triggers-in-database-using-microsoft-sql-server)

Then, you can use a text editor to replace the code you need to replace. Then, you can drop your triggers and recreate them. I don't know if your referring to a production database, or one that you are doing development on. I am assuming from your question that you are prepared to make these major changes to your database. Make sure you back up your database first, in any event.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try to read the link you post. And also I am willing to recreate them because I dont have a choice either.

Comment: SQL encounter an error, OutOfMemoryException by the way I have 100+ tables and most of these tables have at least 3 triggers ( delete, insert, update ). Is there any other way to script it ?

Comment: Not sure why you got the error. In the script, is each create statement separated with a "GO" delimiter, or is it just one CREATE TRIGGER after another? Try separating each CREATE TRIGGER with a GO statement at the end of the trigger. This will separate each one into a separate batch in SSMS.